# Подстановка значение элемента вместо номера

Tags: php, массивы

В отдельном файле хранится массив специальностей и врачей. В базу информацию заносится: специальность словом (строкой) а врач - цифрой. Как сделать, чтобы при выборке записей с БД, вместо цифры, подставлялось имя врача?

```
$listt= array (
  'Педиатр' => array (
     0 => 'Ольга Ганжа',
     1 => 'Александра Смердова',
     2 => 'Елена Гусева',
   ),
  'Терапевт' => array (
     0 => 'Владимир Райко',
     1 => 'Кудайбердиева Анар',
     2 => 'Валентина Бочанова',
     3 => 'Татьяна Кочеткова',
   ),
  'Хирург' => array (
     0 => 'Андрей Сверидюк',
     1 => 'Николай Никитин',
   )
);
```

Comment: SELECT `id_врача` AS `name` -- и потом name использовать в ключах массива

Comment: А причем тут какой-то файл со специальностями? и что за массив указан в вопросе? `специальность словом (строкой) а врач - цифрой` - а зачем в базе в таком формате хранится информация ?

Comment: разберитесь с join. Чтобы вам помочь, нужно знать структуру таблиц